# Define a fold that can not be searched, and that isn't affected by other fold commands?

Tags: folding, file-formats, filetype-perl

POD is a markup file that is used by Perl. It's a pretty unreasonable documentation format that has nothing to do with perl (accept for being the only known use-case), and it's sometimes found [intermingled with code](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlpod.pod#Embedding-Pods-in-Perl-Modules). Think MarkDown-nroff hybrid, but optimized to distract the user from anything they may be doing. You can find more information on it from the official docs on [`perlpod`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlpod), and [`perlpodspec`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlpodspec).

I would like to fold POD, but in such a way that the

- the fold isn't affected by generic operations (`zF` to unfold all) unless I'm explicitly targeting that fold, and for it to otherwise not-expand unless requested.
- for it to **not** be searched when I do `/`

I just don't want to be bothered with POD inside the document.

Comment: Can you give an example or two of embedded POD code? By impervious, do you mean that eg `dap` with a POD fold shouldnt delete the POD ? What do you mean by pod isnt for programmers (isnt it documentation? Did i misunderstand that?)?

Comment: POD is only very seldom unfolded. What I mean is I would ideally like to be able to do folding in other places, and when I set the fold level of unfold all, for the pod to stay folded and out of the way.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use `foldexpr` to do this.

[Here is a gist written by a person on the Internet](https://gist.github.com/bpj/0727f00b5c566bdd8fb0). It defines a `foldexpr` function for folding the `POD` format.

I tried it on a random Perl script I found on [this site (warning no https)](http://sphaerula.com/legacy/Perl/Intermediate/podusage.html#completeExample).

The `foldexpr` seems to work okay. It might work well enough for your use case that you can tweak it.

On the example script I found it managed to hide most but not all of the `POD` documentation.

```
+   +-- 11 lines: !/usr/local/bin/perl---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                   [--clearDb] [--writeToDb]
                                   --path path --division name
                                   --out name

+   +--  2 lines: Examples:--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        perl parseRefSeqGenomes.pl --help

        perl parseRefSeqGenomes.pl --man

        #   Load all RefSeq data:

        perl parseRefSeqGenomes.pl --clearDb --writeToDb
                                   --path /data/genomes --division bct
                                   --out bct.genomes.pep.fasta

+   +-- 82 lines: =head1 DESCRIPTION-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
+   +-- 16 lines: package main;----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        #   Check arguments.

        my( $help, $man, $clearDb, $writeToDb, $division, $path, $outFileName );

        Getopt::Long::GetOptions(
            'help'          =>  \$help,
            'man'           =>  \$man,
            'clearDb'       =>  \$clearDb,
            'writeToDb'     =>  \$writeToDb,
            'division=s'    =>  \$division,
            'path=s'        =>  \$path,
            'out=s'         =>  \$outFileName );

        #   Check for requests for help or for man (full documentation):

        Pod::Usage::pod2usage( -verbose => 1 ) if ( $help );
example.pl
```

Comment: Does this stop searching from within pod?

Comment: @EvanCarroll . Not directly. You can target only open folds for searches https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Search_only_in_unfolded_text . My other answer to your other question https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/19561 will make it impossible to search in the folded POD text even if you want to.